# How to cluster multivariate angular data? Distance measures and algorithms

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, distance

I'd like to cluster a set of multidimensional vectors (n > 10) in which each attribute is an angle. What distance measures and algorithms can I use?

I thought of:
- manhattan distance
- taking max/min of distances between pairs of attributes (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9390236)
- summing angular distances between all pairs of attributes

When it comes to distance measures, Euclidean distance seems very natural and intuitive even for objects located in multidimensional space. However, I didn't found some kind of equivalent for angles.

And algorithms:
- affinity propagation
- dbscan
- in general terms, scikit-learn algorithms, except for K-Means. (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering)

Here are some examples:
['179.5', '58.8', '78.2', '211.8', '295.6', '194.9', '9.3', '328.3', '40.9', '323.1', '17.2']
['171.4', '74.9', '81.5', '204.4', '284.1', '193.8', '2.1', '326.7', '49.3', '310.4', '30.5']
['64.2', '119.8', '147.2', '213.0', '167.4', '256.4', '349.4', '28.3', '325.6', '29.6', '348.0']
By the way, these numbers are dihedral angles.

Comment: Please provide some sample data... This is all but impossible to say what will work.

Comment: That's not what I meant by sample data... I meant data that would allow me to try some clustering algorithm and different distance measurements. This is just 3 data points.

Comment: Here it is: http://speedy.sh/rtrXx/sample.csv

Comment: If you are trying to cluster domain specific information, it makes sense to also explore how other people in the field are doing it. From your mentioning of "dihedral angles", I googled and guessed that you might be interested in clustering molecules. This led me to this find: https://www.chemcomp.com/journal/cluster.htm I'm sure there are many more publications for clustering of molecules in organic chemistry.

Answer (score 4):

Consider mapping the angle to the unit circle. That way distances are close even if two angles are -pi and pi. This would mean that each vector goes from being n-dimensional to (2n)-dimensional.

Then, I'd try all the normal distance measurements.

Comment: So you suggest doing something like this (http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/11016504425/clustering-angles).

Comment: Yes. This seems to be the most obvious mapping of an angle (in wrap-around space) to some more conventional domain. Generally, you want a metric or a kernel where 1 degree is close to 359 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on using k-means, you *must* really map the data to Euclidean space, i.e. to `sin(angle), cos(angle)` for each angle. The reason is that otherwise, the *mean* function does not make sense: the mean of angles `-179` and `+179` should be `-180` (or `+180`), but when done naively, the mean would be `0`, which is the opposite!

If you give other algorithms a try, such as HAC, PAM, CLARA, DBSCAN, OPTICS etc. then you can define a custom distance function, which handles the 360° wrap-around. For example, you could use

```
min(abs(x-y), 360-abs(x-y))
```

and then compute the sum of these, or the sum of squares.

But this approach does not work with k-means!

Comment: Here they explain why it is not possible to use K-Means with distance different than Euclidean: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric